# Check if next character of a match, matches

Tags: javascript, match

in order to explain myself better.

I have the following string

```
var a = 'Dg_DQ_DA'
```

And i pass for example `DQ`

I want to check if string `a` contains `DQ`, that i can do, but also i want to check `DQ` next character, or know what character is only if it matches, i'm kinda stuck on how to do that dumb thing.

Thanks.

Comment: Check if the string contains `"DQ_"` ?

Comment: try if(a.indexOf('DQ_')!=-1){// do your stuff here}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by soktinpk, you can concatenate the "needle" string with "_", and use indexOf as usual: 
`haystack.indexOf(needle + "_") != -1`

Comment: Thanks, i edited the question, made a mistake, i want to know what's the next character, not if it's just an underscore since it can be another different.

Comment: IndexOF is the index at which your needle starts, so if you have `position = haystack.indexOf(needle)`, you can extract it like: `var char = haystack.charAt(position + needle.length);` for example

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
var str = 'Dg_DQ_DA';
//check if string a contains DQ
if(/DQ/g.test(str)){
   var nst = str.match(/DQ./g);
   console.log(nst[0].slice(-1)); //To get the last character
}else{
   //Not Found
}
```

The result of console will be:

`_`